# how to restrict user to enter only 5 and greater after the dot sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

i want to restrict user to enter only 5 and greater than 5 in input type number
allowed value formate is    : 2.54
Restricted value formate is : 2.45
The solution must be in jquery.

Comment: Did you try using a regex for this? What does you current code look like?

Comment: No i am not using regex

Comment: "The solution must be in jquery" - Must it be in jQuery or must it be in javascript?

Comment: Yeah, if jQuery only, there isn't an easy solution.  You need to use some vanilla javascript for this..

Comment: do you have any example of vanilla javascript. please share this

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: This reads like an assignment, the idea of this site is to request help not commission work. Have you tried anything yet yourself?

Comment: post some code sample. So we can go from there.

Comment: yes i have a code $(':input[type="number"]').keydown(function (e) {
    var qty_val = $(this).val();
    if (qty_val.indexOf('.') > -1){
     // find the next index and match if its less than 5 then return false;
    }
   });

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':input[type="number"]').keydown(function (e) {
    var qty_val = $(this).val();
    if (qty_val.indexOf('.') > -1){
        var float_val = parseFloat(qty_val);
        var int_val = Math.floor(float_val);
        if(float_val - int_val >= 0.5){
            // valid
        }
        else{
            // not valid
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because this is a better solution.  I was not aware he was looking for the math on it...

Comment: @Skippy yeah. The problem is poorly described. I didn't uderstand it untill he posted the code sample (which was poorly posted as well).